# Why doesn't the fur follow the rigged mesh?

Tags: rigging, particles, armature, hair

[image]

So I got this model, on which I painted some fur on with the hair particle system and the particle edit tools, I then rigged it, but when I pose the model, the fur stays in place and doesn't follow the geometry of the model! I couldn't find anything on google regarding this issue! How can I get the fur to follow the mesh while posing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Place the *Armature* modifier above the *Particle System* modifier.

[image: modifier stack]